# Get the size of readonly file with GetFiles()

Tags: c#, .net

Does anybody know why I am not allowed to "read" the size of a file that has the "ReadOnly" bit set? I am running my program as Administrator and I am not attempting to write to the file, I can read properties and file size from File Explorer just fine, even with lower credentials, but my software is not allowed to read from a readonly file and gives me an UnAuthorizedAccess exception. I don't see any logic behind this, anybody who does? Is there a workaround?

```
private static double DirSize(DirectoryInfo tdir) {
    double size = 0;
    FileInfo[] files = tdir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files) { size += file.Length; }

    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = tdir.GetDirectories();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs) { size += DirSize(dir); }
    return( size );
}
```

Edit: the file it's complaining about is a shortcut to a directory that is readonly. Security tab shows no problems on both the directory itself and the shortcut. I guess it's not a big deal cause it's just a shortcut, but I like to understand what's going on and want to count that 1 KB shortcut to my totals.

Comment: To figure this out, there's got to be more information from the exception - what is the exception's message?

Comment: There must be more to this than just read-only. Is the path on a network store? Do you have permissions on the files? What is the path?

Comment: The path is: "C:\Users\Test\Documents\Mijn afbeeldingen", which is Dutch for the default Pictures folder. It's a shortcut to "C:\Users\Test\Mijn afbeeldingen". The extra text in the exception message is: "Additional information: Access to C:\Users\Test\Documents\Mijn afbeeldingen denied." (translated from Dutch) and it sais something about "Make sure the file is not readonly", and it indeed is readonly. Permissions are ok, my normal administrator accout has full access and also the real administrator account.

Comment: Even with the edit, there's not enough info. A shortcut will not cause this code to enter the folder so it's not relevant that the folder is readonly.

Comment: `My Pictures` is a special folder, you will not be able to get access to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks DavidG. But why is the Security tab on this file misleading? What's also weird, I do have access to the My Pictures folder it's pointing to, just not to the shortcut itself.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/930128

Comment: Thanks for the link David, it's weird though cause I am running a fresh install of Windows 7 (no upgrade) and unlike the Microsoft ducument, in my case the source of the shortcuts do exist. I guess this is just another annoying Windows issue that is not to be fixed. Thanks for your effort anyway!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, files and directories have different security credentials. You may access a file of a directory easily, but when it comes to a directory itself, you will need to set privileges for the user of your application.

```
Properties -> Security -> Groups or Usernames
```

And you must give access to the user of the application which is trying to access the data. (For example IIS user For web applications)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, although the thing is that the directory is empty and I do already have read and write access to both the directory and the shortcut leading to the directory. I think it's a Windows bug or something. Anyway, it's just a minor problem so I'll leave it unfixed...

Comment: @Saskia Glad if I could help. However I don't think it's a windows bug. You should consider giving full access to the user "Everyone" and see if your code works. If it works, you can be sure that it's a security issue.

Comment: I could do that, but eventually the code is running on other people's computers and I can't have them add "Everyone" to all their files. Furthermore, if my own useraccount plus the administrator accounts are added and I have no access with these accounts, I consider this to be an illogical thing, which I like to call a bug. I should not need "Everyone" in there if my own user account is already in there. I bet its due to the "readonly" bit and it's treating GetFiles() like I'm writing to it or something.

Comment: @Saskia No, I suggested "Everyone" thing just to test if that's the problem. I am no expert on user accounts, however standalone applications requires their own permissions to access such directories. (IIS for web applications, for example.) Anyway good luck.

Comment: yeah I know you meant it just for testing purposes. Software always runs under a particular user; IIS for instance is a daemon and is not running under the account of the user that starts it up (in most cases), so it runs under its own useraccount (Microsoft chose to create some network user account to run the daemon under) and so these rights will also be the security rights of the IIS process and thus the rights used when opening files.